# when I'm going to update node verson facing an warning and failed to update it

Tags: node.js

command : npm install n -g

warning shows: npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@7.3.1: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

please show the image and help me to find out the way to solve this obstacle

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/491), looks like `n` does not support windows. You may try [nvs](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs) or [nvm-window](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)